# Get the hour and minute from the Time String

Tags: android, timepickerdialog

I just want to get the hour and the time from the TimePicker, which I'm storing as a string value. The user initially clicks an editText which will open up a TimePickerDialog. Please find the code below

```
initialTimeEditText.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View view) {
    int mYear;
    int mMonth;
    int mDay;
 if (view == initialTimeEditText) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {
                            String hourString;
                            if (hourOfDay < 10)
                                hourString = "0" + hourOfDay;
                            else
                                hourString = "" + hourOfDay;

                            String am_pm = (hourOfDay < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";

                            String minuteSting;
                            if (minute < 10)
                                minuteSting = "0" + minute;
                            else
                                minuteSting = "" + minute;
                            initialTimeEditText.setText(hourString + ":" + minuteSting + " " + am_pm);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
```

I have this editText named initialTimeEditText, and when I user clicks on the editText, I create a TimePickerDialog. When I am storing the value into the database, I store it as a String. You can see in the code where I setText to the EditText as a String value. This is how I store it in Firebase database

```
String initialTime = initialTimeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
medicationsMap.put("initialTime", initialTime);
```

My question is, I have this value initialTime which is a String and I want to extract the hour and minute value and set it to the calendar instance like

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(),
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePickerDialog.getHour());
```

The code mentioned above is totally a different method. I just have access to the initialTime String value. Can I get the hour and minute value from that String?

Can this be done? If so, any way to do it? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
String[] timeArray = initialTime.split(":");
if(timeArray.length > 0) {
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);


    String[] array2 = timeArray[1].split(" ");

    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(array2[0]);

    String amPm = array2[1];

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(),
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to get the hour and the time from the TimePicker, which I'm storing as a string value. The user initially clicks an editText which will open up a TimePickerDialog. Please find the code below

I have used Stringtokenizer to seperate hour and minute

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(holder.mTitle.getText().toString().trim(), ":");
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    String hourOfDay = st.nextElement().toString();
    String minute = st.nextElement().toString();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hourOfDay));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minute));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}
```